WGPU compute shader inexplicably returns no data
I have a wgsl compute shader, that essentially checks pairs of datapoints and counts the number pairs that meet a certain requirement (passes(i,j) is true) for each point. (ie. if there are 5 passing pairs that include datapoint #3, then the 3rd element in the output buffer would be set to 5).
Here is a simplified MRE of the shader:
@group(0) @binding(0)
var<uniform> uniforms: Uniforms;
@group(0) @binding(1)
var<storage, read> data: array<f32>;
@group(0) @binding(2)
var<storage, read_write> output: array<atomic<u32>>;

fn passes(i: u32, j: u32) -> bool {
    // To be discussed
}


@compute
@workgroup_size(32, 32, 1)
fn main(@builtin(global_invocation_id) global_id: vec3<u32>) {
    if(passes(global_id.x, global_id.y)) {
        atomicAdd(&output[global_id.x], 1u);
    }
}

I had been using an approximation of this requirement, which was fairly easy to calculate, and all results were returning as expected. However, when I attempted to implement the actual requirement, which is slightly more expensive, the shader's output suggested that there were no successful pairs of data (The output buffer was all 0s). I expected this meant the function that checks the requirement was only returning false, due to bad logic. However, if I replaced the final return result; call in the passes function with
// Calculate expensive result
let result = ...; // Lots of vector flops, but no branching

// Calculate cheap approximation
let approximation = ...; // Something along the lines of data[i] < data[j], something simple
return result || approximation;

I was still getting all 0's. This is very odd as the approximation had worked fine on its own, and even if result was always 0 because of a bug, the approximation should still carry through to the return value. My next intuition was that it could be a shader timeout error (perhaps similar to what was discussed here or here). However, if I modify the code again to resemble this:
// Calculate expensive result
let result = ...; // Lots of vector flops, but no branching

// Calculate cheap approximation
let approximation = ...; // Something along the lines of data[i] < data[j], something simple
return approximation;

It runs just the same as when the whole function was just return approximation. The amount of code executed hasn't really changed (I think) but it is now working just fine.
For completeness, here is the rust code responsible for saving that output buffer:

encoder.copy_buffer_to_buffer(&output_buffer, 0, &output_staging_buffer, 0, output_buffer.size());
queue.submit(Some(encoder.finish()));

let output_staging_slice = output_staging_buffer.slice(..);

let (s1, r1) = flume::bounded(1);
output_staging_slice.map_async(MapMode::Read, move |data| s1.send(data).unwrap());

device.poll(wgpu::Maintain::Wait);

if let Ok(Ok(())) = r1.recv() {
    let output_data = output_staging_slice.get_mapped_range();
    let output_result = bytemuck::cast_slice(&output).to_vec();

    drop(output_data);
    output_staging_buffer.unmap();
    Some(output_result)
} else {
    None
}


